# Calling Mastodon API in R Studio

Tags: r, api, mastodon

Please can someone help me figure out what is going on? I used the mastodon library in R Studio to extract some data from the fediverse successfully a while ago. Here is the code I used:

```
tokens <- login("https://mastodon.social/",user = user,pass = password)
```

"user" is my email address.
It worked well initially, but trying it again, I am getting this annoying error message, which I do not understand:

```
Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "response"
```

Please can any good samaritan out there who has used this library in R Studio help me figure out what is going on? I need to prepare a report on this project. Thanks in advance of your help.

Comment: when you say it worked a while ago.  Is it recently or just an year back.  I tried to do this and it is working correctly `tokens$instance#
[1] "https://mastodon.social/"`

Comment: Please note that there could be some functions that get masked when you are loading other packages as well.  You may load it on a fresh R session with only this package loaded

Comment: Hi akrun. By "a while ago" I meant 30mins ago. Thanks for the suggestion about loading the package alone in a fresh R session. I will give that a try.

Comment: you may run `conflicts()` on R console and see if those functions have any masks

Comment: Thanks akrun, loading the library alone in a fresh session actually worked; that was what I was failing to do before.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some functions may have masked the function.  By calling this on a fresh `R` session, it did work

```
tokens <- login("https://mastodon.social/",user = user,pass = password)
tokens$instance
[1] "https://mastodon.social/"
```